# a single svg element with reflex frp

Tags: haskell, svg, reflex

I am trying to write a single SVG element within reflex FRP

```
import Reflex.Dom
import qualified Data.Map as Map

main = mainWidget $ myDiv

myDiv = el "svg" $ do
  elAttr "circle"  $ Map.fromList [ ("cx" , "50") , ("cy", "50"), ("r" , "40"), ("stroke" , "green"), ("fill",  "yellow" )]
```

This does not compile. Hoping [`Data.Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html) is correct. I know from the [quickref](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-dom/blob/develop/Quickref.md) the type signature is:

```
elAttr     :: String ->          Map String String  -> m a -> m a
```

Slightly curious what monad `m` is associated with `mainWidget` but mainly just getting to work.

This is compiled using the sandbox that comes with [reflex](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-platform).

Comment: "This does not compile" - What's the error message?  It's always important to post compiler errors in these cases.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want `el`?

Comment: @alec how do I get the attributes?

Comment: @bheklilr the errors were very long... I can take out some relevant parts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things to fix here.

First, you want to return something, often the basic `return ()` will allow you to compile.

Second, the elAttr takes 2 input types, so after the "circle" you want to put the second argument in parenthesis rather than the `$`.

This is what it looks like:

```
import Reflex.Dom
import qualified Data.Map as Map

main = mainWidget $ myDiv

myDiv = el "svg" $ do
  elAttr "circle"  (Map.fromList [ ("cx" , "50") , ("cy", "50"), ("r" , "40"), ("stroke" , "green"), ("fill",  "yellow" )]) $ return ()
```

After compiling, you should be able to see this in your browser's element inspector.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" src="rts.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="lib.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="out.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg>
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" fill="yellow" r="40" stroke="green"></circle>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to see it show up in the browser, make sure to define this attribute `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/20000/svg"` in your svg element like below with `elDynAttrNS'`:

```
main = mainWidget $ myDiv

myDiv = do
  let attrs = constDyn $ fromList
               [ ("width" , "500")
               , ("height" , "250")
               ]
  let cAttrs = constDyn $ fromList
               [ ("cx", "50")
               , ("cy", "50")
               , ("r", "40")
               , ("stroke", "green")
               , ("stroke-width", "3")
               , ("fill",  "yellow" )
               ]

  s <- elSvg "svg" attrs (elSvg "circle" cAttrs (return ()))
  return ()

elSvg tag a1 a2 = do
  elDynAttrNS' ns tag a1 a2
  return ()

ns :: Maybe String
ns = Just "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

Comment: I observe that `elDynAttrNS` (for elements with namespaces?) is not on the [cheatsheet](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-dom/blob/develop/Quickref.md).